# GETDATE() method for DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have been trying for a while now to get a similar method to `GETDATE()` in DB2 for i. So far I have found the following:

```
current date
current timestamp
current time
```

Would it be possible for me to:

```
 select specific, columns
 from table
 where datefield = current date - 1 day
```

Is this the most efficient way or is there some way I perhaps haven't found yet?

EDIT:

I currently have this:

```
WHERE datefield = - days(date('2013-10-28'))
```

although this isn't helpful as I will need to edit it every day the query runs.

Have now come to this:

```
WHERE datefield = VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD') - 1
```

Except this will not work on the first day of the month as 1 - 1 = 0 and there is no day 0 in a month...

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve ? What is your question ? Do you want a day previous to current day ?

Comment: Here's a little article that might help you out: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html

Comment: select dateadd(dd,-1,getdate()) This will give you the day previous to current day. If this answers you question ...

Comment: @user2919277 - I'd say it's pretty clear that's what the OP is looking for - make that an answer.

Comment: what's stopping you from using current_timestamp - 1?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This will give you yesterday's date:

```
SELECT CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know a certain date range as an alternative you can try the TIMESTAMPDIFF scalar function, read syntax diagramSkip visual syntax diagram
The parameter: 16 indicates it will evaluate per days

The next example determines a range of 70 days as of now.

```
WHERE (TIMESTAMPDIFF(16, CHAR(SYSDATE- CURRENT DATE)) )<70 AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(16, CHAR(SYSDATE- CURRENT DATE)) ) > -1
```

you can take a look on this link for all the details about this method which is supported by DB2: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000861.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-155

Comment: The reference is for DB2 LUW.  A DB2 for IBM i reference can be seen at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscatimedifstmp.htm

Answer (score -6):

```
select dateadd(dd,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: There is no DATEADD() in standard SQL. It's a Microsoft extension. MySQL also has Date_Add(). Similar for GETDATE().